# quickest way to find a child of html element bs4

Tags: python, html, parsing, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have some HTML that has the following structure:

```
<div class="article">
    <h1 class="header">Birth Date between 1919-01-01 and 2019-01-01, Oscar-Winning, Oscar-Nominated, Males (Sorted by Popularity Ascending) </h1>
    <br class="clear"/>
    <div class="desc">
        <span>1-100 of 716 names.</span> // I WANT THIS ELEMENT
        <span class="ghost">|</span> <a class="lister-page-next next-page" href="/search/name?birth_date=1919-01-01,2019-01-01&amp;groups=oscar_winner,oscar_nominee&amp;gender=male&amp;count=100&amp;start=101&amp;ref_=rlm">Next »</a>
    </div>
    <br class="clear"/>
</div>
```

Now I am trying to get a specific element out of this html with bs4. I tried to do:

```
webSoup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
nextUrl = webSoup.findChildren()[2][0]
```

but this gives me the following error:

> return self.attrs[key]
>   KeyError: 0

So, to summarize my question:
How do I get a specific child at a certain index from an html document with bs4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  you want the first match for span following class `desc` then you can use a css [child combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_combinator) to pair the parent class with child element tag:

```
webSoup.select_one('.desc > span')
```

You  can also choose to specify the parent must be a `div`

```
div.desc > span
```

If there is more than one match then use `webSoup.select` and then index into the list returned.

---

You can use:

```
nextUrl = webSoup.findChildren()[3].findChildren()[0]
print(nextUrl)
```

Comment: is there a way to use parent[0][2][3] etc? or an equivalent to this?

Comment: awesome! just what i was looking for!